# How to parse a csv into a dataTable quickly and efficiently using D3 v6

Tags: d3.js, datatables

## What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to load a CSV with 65 thousand rows into a dataTable. Trying to make a static webpage to showcase some data I just parsed,

I'm using the following libraries

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" charset="utf-8"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.23/datatables.min.css" />
```

## What I did

Here is my code on the javascript side. My HTML just has a body and head. The head is then populated with a table

```
var tabulate = function (data, columns) {
var table = d3.select('body').append('table').attr("id", "example").attr("class", "display nowrap")
var thead = table.append('thead')
var tbody = table.append('tbody')

thead.append('tr')
    .selectAll('th')
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append('th')
    .text(function (d) {
        return d
    })

var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('tr')

var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
    .data(function (row) {
        return columns.map(function (column) {
            return {
                column: column,
                value: row[column]
            }
        })
    })
    .enter()
    .append('td')
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.value
    })

return table;
}
d3.csv("all_engineers.csv", function (data) {
    var columns = d3.keys(data[0]);
    tabulate(data, columns);
    $('#example').DataTable();
})
```

## What is the problem?

It's tooooooo slow. It could be due to the big data set. I was wondering if there was an easy fix. I know D3 is super efficient and there might be something I'm not leveraging.

I also can't seem to use this code with d3 v6. I ended up using d3 v3 instead because this is the example I found that worked with datatables.

Thank you in advance for taking the time.

### Update

Thanks to altocumulus
We figured out how to use d3 v6

The old implementation (using D3 V3)
jsfiddle.net/2nwasz43

the Updated Implementation (using D3 V6)
jsfiddle.net/gndv6rq0/1

Comment: I set up two JSFiddles: 1) Your original code: https://jsfiddle.net/2nwasz43/, 2) my adaption of your code running v6: https://jsfiddle.net/gndv6rq0/1/. The dataset is smaller than yours, though. Firing up the dev tools on my machine it takes 1) 12.9 s, 2) 13.5 s to complete the task. Investigating further, you'll see that the `tabulate()` call contributes 1) 840 ms, 2) 970 ms to that overall time which is somewhat around 7 %. Most of the time is spent doing DataTables stuff! Unless you find a way to significantly speed up DataTables I am afraid you are out of luck regarding performance.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought that might be the case. Thank you for doing this with V6. I was getting super annoyed at what I was doing wrong

Comment: @altocumulus any suggested libraries to replace dataTables that might be faster?

Comment: I don’t know. Maybe native HTML5? When it comes to dealing with large datasets I have always been impressed by the performance of the original crossfilter demo which processes and filters 250k records on the fly: https://square.github.io/crossfilter/ Try playing with those filter handles to see the amazing speed the graphs and the table are updated with.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I'm wondering if you might utilize localStorage mechanism for storing and retrieving your data once you've parsed it? I've used LokiJS but I know there are SQLish alternatives. Get d3 to parse your data, store it in a localStorage based DB, and then use something like https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/localstorage.html to retrieve and display it.

Answer (score 0):

Loading time before was taking more than 2 minutes before. I removed a few columns from the CSV and decided to add a loading gif to the HTML page since making this instantaneous was out of the question in terms of what I wanted to do

What really helped reduce the load time was loading the d3 data object directly into the datable instead of putting it in the DOM. I was getting page unresponsive in the latter but that seemed to have gone away in the former.

I'm using d3 version 3 instead of version 6 since the syntax seems cleaner and more familiar to me. If you want to use d3 version 6 then you would need to watch out for the API differences (look at https://jsfiddle.net/gndv6rq0/1 for reference)

What I ended up with was the following script

```
function hideLoader() {
$('#loading').hide();
}

setTimeout(hideLoader, 80 * 1000);

var tabulate = function (columns) {
var table = d3.select('body').select('table')
var thead = table.append('thead')

thead.append('tr')
    .selectAll('th')
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append('th')
    .text(function (d) {
        return d
        })

    return table;
}
d3.csv("All_engineers_reduced.csv", function (data) {
    var columns = d3.keys(data[0]);
    tabulate(columns);
    $('#example').DataTable({
        data: data,
        columns: [
        {
            "data": "Engineer_ID"
        },
        {
            "data": "Arabic_Names"
        },
        {
            "data": "Latin_Names"
        },
        {
            "data": "Field_ID"
        },
        {
            "data": "SubField_ID"
        },
        {
            "data": "Field"
        },
        {
            "data": "SubField"
        }

    ],
    processing: true,
        language: {
            processing: "<img src='https://media1.giphy.com/media/feN0YJbVs0fwA/giphy.gif'>"
        }
    });
    hideLoader();
})
```

The loaded libraries are still

```
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.23/datatables.min.css" />
```

You can see the final result in the link below
https://ebrahimkaram.github.io/LebaneseEngineers/